# Android Looper.prepare() in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

in my application i'm try to retrive data from webservice by AsyncTask. in this code i'm put long operation into AsyncTask but i get this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
icq.ms.Activities.ActivitySendArchive$4.run(ActivitySendArchive.java:298)
01-05 10:52:30.905: E/AndroidRuntime(467): 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

My Code:

```
Thread request_thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new LongOperationList().execute ("");
    }
};
request_thread.start ();
```

`LongOperationList` code block:

```
private class LongOperationList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        G.db.deleteArchive ( G.config_username );
        try {
            getRequestFromServer ( 0, 10 );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if( G.DEBUG ) G.DebugLog.log( e + "" );
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progress_bar.setVisibility ( View.GONE );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

how to  call Looper.prepare() into AsyncTask?

Comment: You have already used AsyncTask for performing network background operation so why you need to execute your async task in another thread???

Comment: don't call AsyncTask from thread

Comment: @andbee Your wel come!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call AsyncTask like:

```
new LongOperationList().execute ("");
```

Answer (score 0):

do not need to start a long operation task from thread so just

**change this to**

```
Thread request_thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new LongOperationList().execute ("");
    }
};
request_thread.start ();
```

**this**

```
new LongOperationList().execute ("");
```